# Solenoid Length In Inductance Formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, inductance

For a long solenoid, when the formula describes solenoid length, is it referring to the length of the wire wrapped around the magnetic core or the length of the core?

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1):

By "length of the solenoid," the formula is referring to the height or width of the solenoid, *not* the length of the wire. Refer to this diagram below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

No, it refers to the height of the (hypothetical) cylinder around which the solenoid is wrapped.

Since this is a homework type question, I will provide hints to derive the formula:

1. What is the magnetic field inside the solenoid with total $N$ turns, height $l$, carrying current $I$?
2. If the number of turns is $N$ and cross sectional area is $A$, what is the magnetic flux $\phi$ through the solenoid due to its own magnetic field? (that will be $N$ times the flux through one turn)
3. Finally, what is self inductance in terms of $\phi$ and $I$?